How can I migrate to apache httpclient5 about Zero Copy Get request
I am migrating to apache httpclient5 from apache httpclint 4.
I use the Zero Copy Get request process as follows.
https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/httpcomponents/httpasyncclient/branches/4.1.x/httpasyncclient/src/examples/org/apache/http/examples/nio/client/ZeroCopyHttpExchange.java?view=markup
I download big files using this Zero Copy.
But, I can not find the Zero Copy process in the httpclient5.
How can I migrate this process?
Thank you.
I read the following document.
https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-5.3.x/index.html

Zero-copy message body transfer is possible with HTTP/1.1 over plain connections only. It cannot work with HTTP of any version over TLS, with HTTP/2 (with an exception of tiny messages that can fit into a single DATA frame) and with HTTP/1.1 and chunk-coding.
Overall, given the widespread use of TLS it was just not worth the effort, so for the time being there is no support for zero-copy message body transfer in HC 5.x

Thank you.
I understood it.
However, it seems to me that when downloading a file, it must be extracted to memory, but does that mean that downloading a large file is impossible?

Zero-copy literally means zero copy, no intermediate in-memory buffer at all. Message content gets streamed directly from a network socket to a file. Normal copy involves a small intermediate buffer. Under no circumstances the entire message body needs to be buffered in memory prior to being saved to a file. At least not by Apache HttpClient

I understood that a little data is buffered, but not the whole data.
With httpclient4, it seemed like the whole data would be buffered, so I asked this
Thank you very much. I will give it a try.

This is not the case. https://github.com/apache/httpasyncclient/blob/4.1.x/httpasyncclient/src/main/java/org/apache/http/nio/client/methods/ZeroCopyConsumer.java#L92 You should however migrate to HC 5.x.

I am sorry.
I understand that memory is not used when using Zero-Copy in HC 4.
When Zero-Copy is not used in HC 4, my verification was that all the data of the file was put on memory.
So I thought the same thing would happen when not using Zero-Copy in HC 5, but I understand that is not the case.

That should not be the case with HC 4.x as well. Zero copy operation - no intermediate buffer, direct copy from a socket to a file, Normal operation - copy through a small intermediate buffer.

I think so. Thank you very much for your response!
